# Is $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\ln(x+a)}{x}$ a notable limit?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to solve this limit:
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0} \dfrac{2e^x - \log_3(x+3) -2}{x} $

rearrangement leave us to:

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0} 2 \cdot\dfrac{(e^x -1)}{x} - \lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln(x+3)}{\ln 3 \cdot x}$

$\displaystyle2 - \dfrac{1}{\ln 3}\cdot \lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln(x+3)}{x}$

is the $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln(x+3)}{x} = 1$ ?

I know that  $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln(x+1)}{x} = 1$ is a notable limit, but I'm not sure about  $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln(x+a)}{x} = 1$

Comment: Well, $\lim_{x \to 0} \ln(x+a) = \ln a$...

Comment: “Notable limits” are whatever your textbook says. This one poses no problem: $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(x+a)}{x}$ doesn't exist for every $a>0$ *except* for $a=1$. Why doesn't it exist? Because the numerator goes to $\log a\ne0$ and the denominator goes to $0$. The limit is either $\infty$ or $-\infty$ when going to $0$ from the left or from the right.

Comment: Yes I understand that. It is one more wrong solution in my exercises book where the solution for limit submitted in the question is $2 - \dfrac{1}{ln 3}$.

Comment: @Jorge There's probably a typo and it should have been $\log_3(x+1)$.

Comment: I think the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

using  L'Hospital rule $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\ln (x+1)}{x} =1$ because if $x=0$ , it is in undetermined form i.e. $(0/0)$ form but $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\ln (x+a)}{x}$ is not in $(0/0 )$  form so it doesn't exist